# Declaration of a function returning a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

struct entry * findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)
{
    while (listPtr != (struct entry *) 0)
        if (listPtr->value == match)
            return (listPtr);
        else
            listPtr = listPtr->next;

    return (struct entry *) 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct entry * findEntry(struct entry * listPtr, int match);
    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    struct entry * listPtr, *listStart = &n1;

    int search;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next  = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next  = &n3;

    n3.value = 100;
    n3.next  =   0;

    printf("Enter value to locate: ");
    scanf ("%i", &search);

    listPtr = findEntry (listStart, search);

    if (listPtr != (struct entry *) 0)
        printf( "Found %i.\n", listPtr->value);
    else
        printf("Not found.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

So for the line:

```
struct entry *findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)
```

Why is there a `*` in front of find entry? Because it is supposed to be a function declaration but `*findEntry`is a pointer? I do not understand what the statement at all....

On the book the explanation is: specifies that the function `findEntry()` returns a pointer to an entry structure and that it takes such a pointer as its first argument and an integer as its second

In that case is the `*` sign needed?

Thank you

Comment: The `findEntry()` function is declared to return a value of type `struct entry *`; that is, a pointer to a `struct entry`, just as your textbook says.  Without the `*`, it would be declared to return a `struct entry` rather than a pointer to one.

Comment: If the code is all in one file as shown, the function declaration inside `main()` is both superfluous and undesirable. If the function is defined in a separate file from `main()`, the function declaration inside `main()` is necessary but undesirable. If a function is defined and used in more than one source file, then there should be a (self-contained and idempotent) header file that defines the function and any necessary structure types that is included by both the file defining the function and the files using the function. This ensures consistency; the declaration in `main()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine someone told you that `23+45` equals `275`, and then explained it by the following logic: we have to calculate `3+4` separately and just keep `2` and `5` on both sides unchanged. This, of course, would make no sense. The proper meaning of `23+45` notation does not imply that one should rip the `3+4` piece out of it and treat it separately.

When you isolate the `*findEntry` from the rest of your declaration and conclude that it declares `findEntry` as a pointer, you actually make the same kind of mistake. There's no such entity as `*findEntry` in your declaration. Declaration grammar dictates that the `(...)` bit on the right binds to the name `findEntry` first. And only after that we get to considering the `*` to the left of the name.

This means that your declaration of `findEntry` begins with `findEntry(...)` binding, which indicates that `findEntry` is a function. Only after that we take into account the `*` bit, obtaining `*findEntry(...)`, which tells us that `findEntry` is a function returning a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of C doesn't give a parameter name to the return value (because it can't be used in the code anyway).  So the declaration:

```
struct entry * findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)
```

Could be written:

```
struct entry *
findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)
```

(and in fact is written that way in some coding standards).

And that declares a function called `findEntry` that returns a pointer to a `struct entry` (a `struct entry *`).  Without the `*` the function would return a `struct entry`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there a * in front of find entry? Because it is supposed to be a function declaration but `*findEntry` is a pointer? I do not understand what the statement at all....

Yes, it indicates that `findEntry` is a function that returns a pointer value.

C declaration syntax is centered around the types of *expressions*.  For example, suppose we have a pointer to an `int`, and we want to access the pointed-to `int` value.  We use the unary `*` operator on the pointer, like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The *expression* `*p` has type `int`, so when we declare the pointer variable `p`, we do so as

```
int *p;
```

The *declarator* `*p` specifies the "pointer-ness" of `p`.  Similarly, suppose we have a function that returns a pointer to `int`, and again, we want to access the pointed-to integer value.  Again, we use the unary `*` operator on the value returned by the function:

```
x = *f();
```

The *expression* `*f()` has type `int`, so when we declare the function, we write

```
int *f(void);  // void means f takes no arguments
```

In this case, both the "function-ness" and "pointer-ness" of `f` are given by the declarator `*f(void)`.

Now, we could decide to assign the return value of `f` to `p`:

```
p = f();
```

Note that in this case we *don't* use the `*` operator on either expression, because this time we're interested in the *pointer* value, not the pointed-to integer value.  But we still need to use the `*` in their declarations to indicate that they deal with pointer values.

In both expression and declaration syntax, the postfix `()` and `[]` operators bind before (have higher precedence than) the unary `*` operator.  Thus:

```
T *f();     // declares f as a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();   // declares f as a pointer to a function returning T
T *a[N];    // declares a as an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];  // declares a as a pointer to an N-element array of T
```

So when you find a somewhat complex declaration, start with the leftmost identifier an work your way out using the precedence rules above.  Apply these rules recursively to any function parameters.  So, given your declaration

```
struct entry * findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match);
```

we read it as

```
               findEntry                                      -- findEntry
               findEntry (                                )   -- is a function taking
               findEntry (              listPtr           )   --   parameter listPtr
               findEntry (             *listPtr           )   --     is a pointer to
               findEntry (struct entry *listPtr           )   --     struct entry
               findEntry (struct entry *listPtr,     match)   --   parameter match
               findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)   --     is an int
             * findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match)   -- returning a pointer to 
struct entry * findEntry (struct entry *listPtr, int match);  -- struct entry
```